# order by last in item in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular table that is ordered by an array. It works like the second level is depending on the first level and the third level is depending on the second and so on..

For example:

A is parent of B, B is parent of C.

The orderby works fine until I wanna reverse it, then I would like only the last child (in above example C) to reorder, and both A and B stay intact.

Is it possible to make this? And how?

In my plunker below I would like only the order of the rows with C to change when clicking the button.

http://plnkr.co/edit/bCwdIg3MNHVdfaX1hvni?p=preview

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Example - example-example105-production</title>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body ng-app="orderByExample">
      <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
         <table class="friend">
            <tr>
               <th>
                  <button ng-click="toggle_order()">switch order</button>
                  <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'group'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
               </th>
            <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
               <td>{{friend.group}}</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

js:

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('orderByExample', [])
        .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.friends = [{
                group: ['A']
            }, {
                group: ['A', 'B1']
            }, {
                group: ['A', 'B1', 'C1']
            }, {
                group: ['A', 'B1', 'C2']
            }, {
                group: ['A', 'B1', 'C3']
            }, ];
            $scope.predicate = 'group'
            $scope.reverse = false;
            $scope.toggle_order = function() {
                $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
            };
        }]);
})(window.angular);
```

Comment: if you have that relationship then you have to somehow map it to a data structure that reflects it. Then you can order it easily. Now all you have is an array with elements. It's just not the proper way to do that and maybe it'll be too complex too.
Or did I get it wrong and the relactionships represented in each `group`  array?

Comment: @Iamisti they are related to eachother but I dont know how to map the data structure like you talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is in plain Javascript.

You can apply a custom sort, which sorts unequal length arrays by length ascending and the rest beginning by the most right part descending.

```js
var data = [
        { group: ['A', 'B1', 'C2'] },
        { group: ['A', 'B1'] },
        { group: ['A', 'B1', 'C1'] },
        { group: ['A'] },
        { group: ['A', 'B1', 'C3'] }
    ];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    var l = Math.min(a.group.length, b.group.length),
        r = a.group.length - b.group.length;

    while (!r && l--) {
        r = b.group[l].localeCompare(a.group[l]);
    }
    return r;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how to apply this into my plunker..could you help?

Comment: sorry, i do not have any clue from angular.